# SAS: why no 'NOTE: variable is unitialized' when uninitialized variable is part of an array?

Tags: arrays, sas, initialization

Admitted, this question is not very interesting, but since the warnings in the sas-log can be very helpful sometimes I'd like to know what is going on here.

Consider the following minimal example. In step0 we created a dataset. In step 1 we want to copy the value of some variable in step0 to step1 but we forgot the correct name of the variable (or we remember correctly but someone changed it when we were away.) I write two versions of step1 named step1a and step1b.

```
Data step0; 
Dog = 1;
run;

Data step1a;
value = cat; 
run;

Data step1b; 
array animals cat;
value = animals[1];
run;
```

Needless to say both version of step1 produce the same dataset, in this case an empty dataset with variables 'value' and 'cat'.

However: when running step1 in the way step1a is written, the SASlog will warn us that something is wrong:

```
NOTE: Variable cat is uninitialized.
```

We can go back to our code, notice that what we think was a cat was actually a dog all along, see the error of our ways and produce the correct dataset we had in mind.

When on the other hand running step1 in the way step1b is written, the SASlog will act as if everything is perfectly fine and we can go out singing and dancing in the street only to find out years later that the value of dog is lost forever.

So the question is: why does SAS think in the second case that no warning is needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you HAVE initialized the variable in the third example, via the array declaration.  When you declare an array, any variables not already existing are initialized to Numeric missing, unless you either specify $ in the array definition (in which case they are character missing (length 8)), or you specify an initialized value.